# How to use C# 6.0 or 7.0 in an old ASP.NET Website (not Website Project)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple old ASP.NET webforms websites (this is how to create one from scratch):
[image]

They are not Website Projects.

ASP.NET Websites seem to be stuck at C# 5. When trying to use features from c# 6 or C# 7 you get an error:
[image]
Trying to use the light bulb upgrade option fails:
[image]
Trying any of the other options found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version fail too since there is no .csproj file. or an option in the Project Properties page to change the language version.

Here is what the Build tab looks like on an ASP.NET Website (no Advanced button):
[image]

I installed the Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package but that made no difference.

Any Ideas if this can be done at all in an ASP.NET website?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you install the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` it will update your `web.config` file to use the current version - right now it's on `7.3`:

```xml
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" 
        compilerOptions="/langversion:7.3 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" 
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, 
              Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, 
              Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" 
        compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" 
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, 
              Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, 
              Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Comment: @Klesun Back at you, bro

Comment: It should be noted, though, that `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` installed via NuGet has [a certain side effect](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build/71302) of locking the /bin/ directory which prevents IDE from deleting it on build and causing inconsistent state if you remove assemblies from the project: these assemblies will stay in /bin/ unless you manually terminate VBCSCompiler.exe from task manager. It is supposed to be prevented by UseSharedCompilation:false msbuild option, but I dunno how to pass it to codedo

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the project, click on properties, select build tab, click on Advance button at right bottom, select Language Version and click on OK button.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please see the last image I just added. You will notice there is no "Advanced..." tab. Your answer would be correct if this was a Website Project.

Comment: try to modify the langversion in web.config as below:

<system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
                type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
            
    </system.codedom>

Comment: I figured out that adding `"Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform"` Nuget package will add your lines to the `web.config` and the needed `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll` file to the bin folder and solve the issue. If you create an answer with this solution I will mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

I run into a project, it is an old asp.net project without .csproj file.

If you create a new asp.net website, you will find the .csproj file, and you can use C# version above 5 happily.

So the problem become: how to generate .csproj file for the old project.

Just create a new project, and copy the code from old project inside Visual Studio. And then copy the new .csproj to the old project. And then your old asp.net project refreshed.:)

Comment: You make it sound so simple ;-).  Actually it is pretty simple.  I was wondering why I couldn't find a .proj file.