# A Dictionary with a tuple as key could not be compiled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, generics, webforms, visual-studio-2022

I keep having this error within a line of my code and I can't seem to fix it.

1. error BC30182: Type expected.
2. error BC30638: Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.

Here is my code:

```
Dim upload As Dictionary(Of (Long, Long, Long), Long)
```

It is located in Page_Prerender . The LangVersion for :default, latest or 16.9 could not be set also. (*the value 'default' is invalid for option 'langversion'*). The error occurs in vs2019 and vs2022 community version. However it runs fine on LinqPad5 and other VB project. I deleted all my obj files and rebooted :(. Maybe I have to delete some other object files in appdata or elsewhere?

I tried to compile it in previous version of visual studio, deleted obj files, changed langversion.

Comment: When you're asking a question about an error, *always* give the precise error you're encountering, *in the question*. It's unclear what this has to do with asp.net and webforms, btw... you might want to clarify that.

Comment: Have you tried using `ValueTuple` explicitly, e.g. `Dictionary(Of ValueTuple(Long, Long, Long), Long)`?

Comment: Your existing code works for me: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/7a22d3ff204047fe1868ad8b9524823f

I do wonder whether it *is* specific to webforms, due to that using an older version of VB. It would be easy to test that in a simpler way - can you use tuples *at all* in your webform?

Comment: I suspect that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130824 is basically what you need, but the VB equivalent.

Comment: that results in BC32093 'Of' required when specifying type arguments for a generic type or method. The valuetypes are just examples. Other tuples contain reference types

Comment: Again: can you use tuples *at all* in your webform? If it just turns out this is "you're using an older version of the language" then the link to the other Stack Overflow question is relevant - you need to change your web.config.

Comment: You are correct. It works. Dim upload = New Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Long, Long, ResponseContent), Long). Thank you.